# jquery combing fields for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

My webpage has 3 select boxes where the user can select day, month and year
When the page loads it displays "Day" in the day select option, Name of month in month (for example January):

```js
    $("#join").validator.addMethod('check_dob', function(value, element, params) {
        //unsure about this logic
    }, "Enter the number of persons (including yourself)");    
    
    
   $("#join").validate({
    rules : {
     firstname: "required",
     lastname: "required",
     dob: { check_dob: ['day', 'month', 'year'] }
    },
    
    messages: {
     firstname: "Firstname is required",
     lastname: "Lastname is required",
      }
    
   });
```

```html
<label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>

<!-- day -->
<select name="day" id="day">
<option value='0'>Day</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='6'>6</option><option value='7'>7</option><option value='8'>8</option><option value='9'>9</option><option value='10'>10</option><option value='11'>11</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='13'>13</option><option value='14'>14</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='16'>16</option><option value='17'>17</option><option value='18'>18</option></select>

<!-- month -->
<select name="month" id="month">
<option value="0">Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>         
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<!-- year -->
<select name="year" id="year">
<option value='0'>Year</option><option value='1996'>1996</option><option value='1995'>1995</option><option value='1994'>1994</option><option value='1993'>1993</option><option value='1992'>1992</option><option value='1991'>1991</option><option value='1990'>1990</option><option value='1989'>1989</option><option value='1988'>1988</option><option value='1987'>1987</option><option value='1986'>1986</option><option value='1985'>1985</option><option value='1984'>1984</option><option value='1983'>1983</option><option value='1982'>1982</option><option value='1981'>1981</option></select>
```

when the form submits I want the form to validate and if the user hasn't selected either day, month, year he will get an error message. That is 1 error message, not 3. I t should be displayed to the right for the year input field (so it align with other validate error messages)

unsure how to code this, been googling and read http://jsfiddle.net/hBXL6/ but it didn't work for me. Any guideance would be great

Answer (score 0):

Well using jQuery I would remove what you have there and go for an easier option check, since were based off values .val() will work just fine; I've assembled a jsfiddle that works to what I think is what you're expecting. (I hope) which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/dhershman/33pv91am/

```
    var day = $('#day option:selected').val();
    var mnth = $('#month option:selected').val();
    var year = $('#year option:selected').val();
```

It will look at your options setup, see if a value is equal to zero (you can also make this less than or equal to in case of negatives for whatever reason) and then throws your error else it will register as correct.